# How to set yellow, red display priority in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Yellow and red errors are happening at the same time in vscode.

At this time, I want the red error to be displayed more forward than the yellow error.

In other words, I want to increase the priority of red errors in vscode so that red errors appear on the screen before yellow errors. Is there any way?

I'm currently using the fira font in vscode, and below is my current screen and what I want it to look like.

*screen i want

[image]

*my current screen

[image]

Comment: don't tag the question with irrelevant tags

Comment: if you look close the squiggle under todo is red, just customize the colors so the red color has contrast against the yellow color, maybe make the yellow color more transparent

Comment: Sorry, I will write a post with caution in the future. And thank you so much for your answer